# css icons will not display in header

Tags: css

I create just below header,but it will not display any icons and it displays    home,blog,mail,contact links in same place.

my HTML file is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Index file for header</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="header.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <ul id="menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="home">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="blog">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="mail">MAIL</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="contact">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS file as follows:In css file inside container home,blog,mail,contact menus are displayed 
  as one below one.

```
#container{
    background:url("back.jpg") repeat;  
    background-position:0 0;
    height:178px;
    width:1000px;  
}
ul#menu{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    position:relative;  
}
ul#menu li a{    
    background-position:left top;
    position:absolute;
    text-indent:70px;
    display:block;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
ul#menu li a:hover{
    color:white;
    background-position:left center;
}
ul#menu li a .home {
    background-image: url('homeicon.jpg');
    width:50px; height:56px;
    left:80px;
    top:100px;
}
ul#menu li a .blog {
    background-image: url('blogicon.jpg');
    width:50px; height:56px;
    left:80px;
    top:120px;
}
ul#menu li a .mail {
     background-image: url('mailicon.jpg');
     width:50px; height:56px;
     left:80px;
     top:140px;
}  
ul#menu li a .contact {
    background-image: url('contacticon.jpg');
    width:50px; height:56px;
    left:80px;
    top:160px;
}
```

Please give the solution.

Comment: are the images in the same folder as the css file?

Comment: Check the images path (relative)

Comment: I think this is the image path issue.

Answer (score 0):

For your First problem Change

```
ul#menu li a .mail
```

to

```
ul#menu li a.mail
```

The Correct usage of the css selector is as follows

```
div p   Selects all <p> elements inside <div> elements
```

make sure the imageURL's are correct and there is images in the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

Remove space between tag a and class identification. Because your classes with backgroud images are for tag , like ul#menu.

Example
ul#menu li **a.home**

Check manual: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp